# Drawing on ScrollView's contentView disappears when content size is too big

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a weird issue with `UIScrollView`, custom drawing on scrollview's contentView is disappears when the scrollView content size is too large.

I have `graphView` which draws a line graph with the values from a `startDate` to `endDate`.  I have added this graph to a scrollView. Graph is scrollable to both the axis. Which works perfectly fine when the number of days between the startDate and endDate is less or in other words the scrollView contentSize is less.

Line chart is dots connected with lines, Here dots are nothing but `UIButtons` with images added as subView. And lines are drawing using

```
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, goPoint.x, goPoint.y);
```

Now the problem starts when the graphs scale is too big(X-Axis: endDate-startDate). `GrpahView` frame and `scrollView` contentSize is around `NSRect: {{0, 0}, {8887, 423}}`View is messed up I can see only dots no lines at all.

Has anyone had this issue with scrollView?. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue building a graphic, and finally the main problem was that the coordinates of the points where floats with decimals, I converted them to NSInteger and everything worked. Hope it helps.

Comment: My coordinates are integer only. still the same issue